# how to print this pattern in java i have no idea how

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop

i cant print this pattern :

```
1 2 3 4 *

1 0 0 * 5

1 0 * 0 5

1 * 0 0 5

* 2 3 4 5
```

i tried to print but only on row :

public class Pattern {

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        for(int j=1;j<=5;j++)
        {
            if(j>4) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(j);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a "design pattern", you should tag with `java` only. Next, could you precise the logic of the pattern you want to print ? (i) a star on column 5-N+1 on line N (ii) zeros on all othe columns except for the first and the last (iii) all numbers but the star on first and last line ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to consider the logic of this output:

You have an NxN matrix, with rows and columns numbered 1..N.

- If you're on the secondary diagonal (i.e. row+column=N+1), print a `*`
- Else, if you're on the borders (i.e., either the row or the column is 1 or N), print the column number
- Else, print a `0`

Now, you just need to convert this logic to Java:

```
int size = 5;

for (int i = 1; i <= size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= size; ++j) {
        char ch;
        if (i + j == size + 1) {
            ch = '*';
        } else if (i == 1 || i == size || j == 1 || j == size) {
            ch = (char) ('0' + j);
        } else {
            ch = '0';
        }
        System.out.print(ch + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and i'am probably in no place to tell you that, but you should consider that this looks a lot like some kind of IT student's exercise made for them to discover the basics (i've went myself trough that a few years ago) and you just served him the answer on a plate. I'am not sure if this will be more helpfull than a comment on his post made of what you posted before the code. :/ By this i mean: guidance on how to resolve the problem rather than straight up giving the answer. (even tho you gave both, the former would suffice)